# How do you install tf_transformations?

Tags: ros, ros2, tf2, tutorials, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently been following the [ROS 2 Galactic tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials.html) and I've reached "[Introduction to tf2](http://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Tf2/Introduction-To-Tf2.html)". I wasn't able to install the demos with `sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-turtle-tf2-py` for some reason, so I tried building from source. But I can't seem to install a package I appear to be missing.

Here's how I set up the workspace:

```
$ mkdir -p min_ws/src
$ cd min_ws/src/
$ git clone https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials.git -b ros2
Cloning into 'geometry_tutorials'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 614, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (195/195), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (139/139), done.
remote: Total 614 (delta 101), reused 112 (delta 48), pack-reused 419
Receiving objects: 100% (614/614), 118.59 KiB | 499.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (320/320), done.
$ cd ..
$ rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro galactic -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
turtle_tf2_py: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [tf_transformations]
```

I have tried searching for where this package to see how to install it but nothing came up. I have also tried

```
sudo apt install tf_transformations
sudo apt install python-transforms3d-pip
sudo apt install transforms3d
```

(I have done `pip3 install transforms3d` already)

I tried to move on but as we expect, the node runs into

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_transformations'
```

Here's a snippet from `ros2 doctor --report`

```
   PLATFORM INFORMATION
system           : Linux
platform info    : Linux-5.11.0-22-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
release          : 5.11.0-22-generic
processor        : x86_64

   RMW MIDDLEWARE
middleware name    : rmw_cyclonedds_cpp

   ROS 2 INFORMATION
distribution name      : galactic
distribution type      : ros2
distribution status    : active
release platforms      : {'rhel': ['8'], 'ubuntu': ['focal']}
```

---

EDIT: Added info on how I set up the workspace, and how I called `rosdep`.

In response to @tfoote's comment:

```
$ sudo apt install ros-galactic-tf-conversions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-galactic-tf-conversions
$ sudo apt install ros-galactic-tf2-conversions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-galactic-tf2-conversions
```

I'm not sure how, but I guess there's something wrong with my installation. Here is what I did before:

- `sudo apt install ros-galactic-desktop`
- `sudo apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions`

Adding to `.bashrc`:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc | tail -n 10
## ROS sourcing
# ROS 2 core - underlay
source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash
# colcon_cd
source /usr/share/colcon_cd/function/colcon_cd.sh
# Where ROS stack is
export _colcon_cd_root=~/ros2_install
# Choose ROS_DOMAIN_ID
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0
```

Seems like I have some `tf2` stuff, but not `ros-galactic-tf-conversions`:

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep "ros-galactic-tf"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

ros-galactic-tf2-bullet/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210701.001325 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-eigen-kdl/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210630.230132 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-eigen/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210701.001337 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-geometry-msgs/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210701.001341 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-kdl/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210701.001149 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-msgs/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210630.224910 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-py/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210630.232207 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-ros-py/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210630.232545 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-ros/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210701.000424 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-sensor-msgs/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210701.001410 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2-tools/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210630.232718 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-galactic-tf2/focal,now 0.17.2-1focal.20210630.224852 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384871/how-do-you-install-tf_transformations?/) by [Cadmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/81960/cadmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a ROS package. https://index.ros.org/p/tf_transformations

If you want the tf_transformations package from apt for galactic you should install `ros-galactic-tf-transformations` If rosdep is giving you that error it doesn't know that you want galactic. You should either source your galactic workspace setup file to get ROS_DISTRO set or manually set it to `galactic` it so rosdep knows you want galactic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-08-23**:
For easier help in the future, please show your full command that you're running not just the error message. And also explain how to setup your workspace. I had to make a lot of informed guesses to provide this answer.

**Comment by [Cadmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/81960/cadmus/) on 2021-08-23**:
Thanks for your time and your contributions to ROS. I couldn't get very far with your suggestions, but I have added the missing information to the question and added more information below the line to make my situation clearer.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-08-24**:
Sorry I typoed when I typed the package name. It should be `ros-galactic-tf-transformations`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to just install `tf-transformations` with:

`sudo apt install ros-galactic-tf-transformations`

Also note from: https://github.com/DLu/tf_transformations

> To use this package, you need to
> manually install the transforms3d
> library.
>
> `sudo pip3 install transforms3d`
>
> At the present time, you cannot
> install transforms3d via Ubuntu
> debian, nor can you force the
> installation of the tf_transformations
> package to also include transforms3d.

---

Originally posted by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) with karma: 100 on 2021-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1